# create / edit file in bash with root privileges

Tags: bash, root

I am creating then writing to a file in bash4, in a directory with root privileges.

I looked at these results from stackoverflow:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37875/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-file-which-has-only-root-write-permission-and-to-continue

But not helping me.
Below `$fName` contains path to file.

First I touch the file: `sudo touch $fName;`

I am writing a key value pair (YAML) and this works:

```
echo " "$key": "$value
```

But when I try to write to the file `$fName` as in:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "  "$key": "$value >> $fName';
```

or even:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo \"  "$key": "$value\ >> $fName';
```

does not work.

Get various errors:

> Bad substitution, command not found etc.

I was also trying to write to memory or /tmp and then move it to the directory.

Would that be a better idea? Somehow that did not work either.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you. All your solutions work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all things including variables will be regard as string but not variable!

Does this work? `sudo sh -c "echo \" $key: $value \" >> $fName"`

Comment: Thank you. All your solutions work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to preserve the quotes around `$fName` to protect against a space in the `path/filename`:

```
sudo bash -c "echo \"  $key: $value\" >> \"$fName\""
```

Comment: Thank you. All your solutions work. Much appreciated!